# In what directory does virtualenvwrapper store site packages by default?

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Virtualenvwrapper provides several variables:

```
$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_ENV_BIN_DIR       
$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PROJECT_FILENAME  
$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT            
$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_CLONE
$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR          
$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON            
$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV        
$VIRTUAL_ENV
```

I believe I am finding my virtual environment by `cd $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR` and going to the name of the environment I created (`cd my_environment`).

That has three directories: `bin`, `include` and `lib`. Unfortunately, none of these seems to contain the `site-packages` directory.

Where would I go to find these site-packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`site-packages` is located in the `lib/python{major}.{minor}/` subdirectory of your virtualenv.

e.g. in a Python 2.7 virtualenv:

```
$ ls -d lib/python?.?/site-packages/
lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

but in a Python 3.4 virtualenv the version number again matches:

```
$ ls -d lib/python?.?/site-packages/
lib/python3.4/site-packages/
```

You can use:

```
$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/`$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python -c "import sys; print('python{0.major}.{0.minor}'.format(sys.version_info))"`/site-packages/
```

if you wanted an absolute path, using the currently active virtualenv Python binary to produce the version number.